# Why does camel neglect proxy details set as part of the Header information

Tags: java, spring, apache, apache-camel

I have recently been facing issues with http4 and http component with spring.
if i configure proxy details as part of the URL,it works, but if i set them as part of the header information, it does not work even with latest version of 2.15.1,

why these inconsistencies.

Regards
Ram

Answer (score 0):

When using proxy then the http client needs to setup stuff prior to be used. The header information can only control some parts such as the context path / query parameters etc. But not proxy / SSL etc that has to be setup prior.

You can use a "dynamic to" if you want a full dynamic endpoint on the fly. See: http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html